# Redirect users from the webroot in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, deployment

I am trying to go through the deployment process with a cakePHP application. I am struggling to figure out how to disable access to my webroot folders.

For instance, I have all the images for the site in webroot/images

If a user tries to access this page as a URL it allows them to see a list of all the images used throughout the site. Same thing with webroot/js, webroot/css, etc.

How do I disable access to those folders through the URL?

Thanks!

Comment: Burzum's answer is correct, but I just want to point out that directory listing of your webroot directory is not really a security risk. You shouldn't keep anything in there that isn't meant to be public and even with directory listing turned off, someone could still compile a list of all of your files by parsing your HTML. Again, though, this is NOT a security risk. Your images, CSS, JavaScript etc is supposed to be public. If if is not, move it out of your webroot!

Comment: Maybe it isn't a security risk, but I've had some annoyances with broken iframe links to a webroot folder. It would be better for it to not display anything or show an error message than to display a list of files.

Comment: @tykenn that's what I was thinking as well.  All that information is public, so there's nothing sensitive in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to disable directory listing? Or deny access to the images itself?

Apache: http://www.htaccess-guide.com/disable-directory-listings/

Nginx: http://nginxlibrary.com/enable-directory-listing/

The link for nginx is about how to enable it but well, the only difference would be the on/off setting.

If you want to avoid that a user can directly access the images you'll have to pass them through a script (check the CakePHP MediaView class) and not put them into the webroot.